# Aggregating hours to days in R?

Tags: r

I have the following table:

```
   date                    status    
1 2015-07-13 12:27:30      1
2 2015-07-22 14:36:09      1
3 2015-07-27 09:03:07      1
4 2015-07-27 17:06:04      1
5 2015-07-28 10:01:38      1
```

And want to aggregate the number of occurrences by day:

```
   date            status  sum    
1 2015-07-13       1       1   
2 2015-07-22       1       1
3 2015-07-27       1       2
4 2015-07-28       1       1
```

Comment: Share your code which you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 'date' column is `POSIXct` class, we can use `dplyr` to aggregate by group.  We group by 'date' after converting to `Date` class and use `summarise` to select the `first` observation of 'status' and create the 'sum' column as the number of elements (`n()`) per each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
         group_by(date=as.Date(date)) %>%
         summarise(status= first(status), sum= n())
df2
#         date status sum
#1 2015-07-13      1   1
#2 2015-07-22      1   1
#3 2015-07-27      1   2
#4 2015-07-28      1   1
```

---

We could also do this using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`),  grouped by the 'date' column after conversion to `Date` class, we select the first observation of 'status' and the number of elements (`.N`) as the 'sum' column

```
 setDT(df1)[,list(status=status[1L], sum=.N) , by = .(date=as.Date(date))]
 #         date status sum
 #1: 2015-07-13      1   1
 #2: 2015-07-22      1   1
 #3: 2015-07-27      1   2
 #4: 2015-07-28      1   1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1436804850, 1437590169,
1438002187, 
1438031164, 1438092098), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
 status = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("date", "status"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Regarding the first method, how would I save it to a new subset?

Comment: @ttct Just assign the results to a new object i.e. `df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(...`

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of trying a base solution:

> ave and aggregate

```
df1$sum <- ave(df1$status, as.Date(df1$date), FUN = "sum")
aggregate(df1[-1], list(as.Date(df1$date)), FUN=head, 1)
```

Output:

```
     Group.1 status sum
1 2015-07-13      1   1
2 2015-07-22      1   1
3 2015-07-27      1   2
4 2015-07-28      1   1
```

> ave and removing the duplicates after converting the date column

```
df1$sum <- ave(df1$status, as.Date(df1$date), FUN = "sum")
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
df1[!duplicated(df1$date),]
```

Output:

```
        date status sum
1 2015-07-13      1   1
2 2015-07-22      1   1
3 2015-07-27      1   2
5 2015-07-28      1   1
```